# Replace double quote in javascript variable string

Tags: javascript, replace, double-quotes

How to replace all double quotes (") instance from a javascript variable string?

Here's my code

```
var double_quote_with_string = "Test "Double Quote" Test";
var replace_double_quote = double_quote_with_string.replace(/"/g, "\"");
alert(replace_double_quote);
```

I want the alert result should be - **Test "Double Quote"** Test

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k1maf209/1/ (this is not working)

Any idea?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Syntax highlight on jsfiddle and here screams about where you've made a mistake.

Comment: Mix single and double quote: `var double_quote_with_string = 'Test "Double Quote" Test';`

Comment: Do this: 'Test "Double Quote" Test';

Comment: i am agree with zerkms

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but my question is how to replace it . Not changing the string to make it syntatically correct. This string is populated from an external source, so when I get a variable string source there are double quotes... sorry I should have added this detail...

Comment: To replace it the way you want, use `double_quote_with_string.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");

Comment: @skypjack it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

When you try this,

```
var double_quote_with_string = "Test "Double Quote" Test";
```

this is syntactically incorrect. If you want quotes in your string try enclosing it in single quotes `'`,

```
var double_quote_with_string = 'Test "Double Quote" Test';
```

Or use escape character `\`

```
var double_quote_with_string = "Test \"Double Quote\" Test";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var double_quote_with_string = 'Test "Double Quote" Test'; 
alert(double_quote_with_string );
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle. I have replaced all the double quotes with single quotes.

[edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1maf209/2/)

```
var double_quote_with_string = 'Test "Double Quote" Test';
var replace_double_quote = double_quote_with_string.replace(/"/g,       "'");
alert(replace_double_quote);
```